# ボタンの無効化が上手くいきません。

Tags: swift, ios

```
stopButton.isEnabled = false
print("ループの前")
for _ in 0...(startPoint) {
    sample = readerOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
    while reader.status != AVAssetReaderStatus.reading {
        sleep(UInt32(0.1))
    }

}
print("ループの後")
```

上記のようなソースですが、
ビデオファイルからサンプルバッファを取り出すループで、
ビデオの頭出しをしています。
このループの前でstopButtonを無効にしても、
ボタンが有効のままです。
ループが終了したところで無効になります。

ループの前でちゃんと無効化する方法はないでしょうか。
よろしくご教示のほどお願いします。

===========================

```
let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: fileURL, options: options)
var reader: AVAssetReader! = nil
do {
    reader = try AVAssetReader(asset: avAsset)
} catch {
    #if DEBUG
    print("could not initialize reader.")
    #endif
    return
}
guard let videoTrack = avAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).last else {
    #if DEBUG
    print("could not retrieve the video track.")
    #endif
    return
}
let readerOutputSettings: [String: Any] = 
[kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : 
Int(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange)]
let readerOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: videoTrack, 
outputSettings: readerOutputSettings)
reader.add(readerOutput)
reader.startReading()

var sample:CMSampleBuffer!        
stopButton.isEnabled=false

for _ in 0...(startPoint) {
    sample = readerOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
    while reader.status != AVAssetReaderStatus.reading {
        sleep(UInt32(0.1))
    }
}
```

ちょっと前のコードから書いてみました。
startPoint はビデオのフレーム数で、その数値を直接設定できないか
色々と探したんですが、見つける事が出来ず、
不甲斐ないことに、そのフレーム数まで空回りさせています。

ご指摘頂いた timerange は
フレーム数の直接設定のヒントかと思い、
reader もしくは　readerOutput のなかに
timerange　に関する何かないか探してみましたが
上手く解決出来ませんでした。
よろしくお願いします。

dispatchQuene
でちゃんと？動いてはいます。
ですが、ループ後の処理で（そのコードは書いていませんが）
main thread でしかやってはいけないよと
warningが出ていてます。
この解決も上手くいってはいません。

Comment: UI要素の更新は、通常現在のアクションメソッド(あるいは、その他UIスレッドで呼び出されるメソッド)が終了してから有効になります。単に「ボタンの無効化が上手くいきません。」については、user17014 さんの書かれたような対応でなんとかなると思うのですが、そもそも「頭出し」と書かれているそのループがかなり怪しいのですが…。`UInt32(0.1)`の値は常に0になりますから、その行は`sleep(0)`と同じ、つまり何もしない単純ループと言うことになります。一度`status`が`.completed`になると、CPU使用率100%で無限ループに入ってしまいます。`timeRange`が使えない、またはうまく動かない状況でもあるのでしょうか? その「頭出し」の処理は見直された方が良いかと思います。

Comment: while reader.status != AVAssetReaderStatus.reading {
        sleep(UInt32(0.1))
    }
を削除しても同じでした。

Comment: 申し訳ありませんが、「while reader.status != AVAssetReaderStatus.reading { sleep(UInt32(0.1)) } を削除」したら解決するとはどこにも書いていません。その部分が「頭出し」としては不適切なコードであるだけです。私のコメントにある`timeRange`に関する質問についても何らかの返信をいただけたら嬉しいのですが。(「ボタンの無効化」については直接の関係はありませんので、無視していただいても、問題ありませんが…。)とりあえずuser17014さんの回答で、「問題が解決された」とお考えでしたら、「承認」の操作をお願いします。

Comment: 投稿を編集しました。コメントに対して、投稿を編集した場合、コメントした方にちゃんと届くのか心配です。どんどん投稿文が長くなってしまいそうです。

Comment: 私の下手なコメントのせいで、投稿を長くして(質問の範囲を広げさせることになって)しまい申し訳ありません。(一般的には無闇に元の質問から範囲を広げるのはあまり良くないこととされています。)ただ、「頭出し」の方法については、確実に解決して置かれた方が良いように思います。コメント先に確実に通知が飛ぶようにするには、@たきちゃん のように、半角`@`の後ろに通知を送りたい相手のscreen nameをつけて、半角スペースで次の文字との間を区切ってください。とりあえず`timeRange`を使う場合の情報とコード例などを後ほど回答の形で示してみますので、内容が見れるようになったらお試しください。

Comment: とりあえず、回答を書いてみました。お示しいただいた以外の部分がどうなっているかわからないので、確実にうまくいくかどうか試せていないのですが、お時間をとってお試しの上、何かありましたらコメントしてください。(回答にコメントをつけたら、回答者には確実に通知が飛ぶはずです。)ちなみに先のコメントの`@`は、コメント内の話で、編集した投稿内だと多分通知は飛ばないと思います。念のため。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

とりあえず、`timeRange`を使うコード例を示しておきます。`let startTime = ...`がフレーム数から`CMTime`を求めている(*)部分になります。

```
    //...
    reader.add(readerOutput)
    //###↓
    let frameRate = videoTrack.nominalFrameRate
    let startTime = CMTime(value: CMTimeValue(startPoint), timescale: CMTimeScale(frameRate))
    let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: startTime, end: .positiveInfinity)
    reader.timeRange = timeRange //読み込む範囲を`timeRange`で指定
    //###↑
    reader.startReading()

    stopButton.isEnabled = false

    //以下の時間のかかる処理は別スレッドで起動(そうしないと`stopButton.isEnabled = false`が効かない)
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        //「頭出し」の処理は何も必要がない。
        //次に`copyNextSampleBuffer()`を呼ぶと`timeRange`の`start`で指定した時刻のフレームが読み込まれる
        //...
        //別thread内で「main thread でしかやってはいけない」処理を書くための定型句
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //「main thread でしかやってはいけない」処理(UIの更新もそう)はこの中に書く
            //...
            //例えばstopButtonを有効化しても良いタイミングになったら
            self.stopButton.isEnabled = true
            //...
        }
    }
    //非同期に処理を起動したら、同じメソッド内では何もしてはいけない(と思った方が良い)
```

とりあえず、公式ドキュメントは[`timeRange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetreader/1386400-timerange)やら、[`CMTime.init(value:timescale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/cmtime/1489173-init)やら。"AVAssetReader seek timeRange"辺りで検索すると(英語だったり、SwiftじゃなくObjective-Cだったりしますが)コード例が見られると思います。

で、(*)なのですが、

- ビデオのフォーマットがフレームレート固定でない場合
- (固定だとしても)29.97fpsとかの中途半端な数字の場合

なんかに正確な位置から頭出しをしてくれるとは限りません。

従って、1フレーム単位で正確な頭出しが必要な場合には、(`AVAssertReader`を使うなら)「フレーム数まで空回り」も仕方ないかと思います。ただし`while reader.status != AVAssetReaderStatus.reading`の部分は余計でしょう。[`AVAssertReader`のドキュメント](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetreader/1390211-status)を見ても`copyNextSampleBuffer()`が`nil`を返したときには`status`のチェックをすべきだとしか書いていません。

```
    //...
    reader.add(readerOutput)
    reader.startReading()

    stopButton.isEnabled = false

    //以下の時間のかかる処理は別スレッドで起動(そうしないと`stopButton.isEnabled = false`が効かない)
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        //どうしてもフレーム単位にしたい時の「頭出し」の処理
        seek: for _ in 0..<startPoint {
            let sample = readerOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
            if sample == nil {
                let status = reader.status
                switch status {
                case .cancelled:
                    //キャンセルされた時の処理
                    //...
                    break seek //別スレッドでの処理を終了したいならreturn(以下同様)
                case .completed:
                    //全部のデータを読み込み終わった時の処理
                    //...
                    break seek
                case .failed:
                    //何らかのエラー
                    //...
                    break seek
                case .unknown:
                    //startReading()を呼ぶ前の`status`を参照しない限り普通はあり得ない
                    //...
                    break seek
                case .reading:
                    //`status`が`reading`で`nil`が返ることはないはずだが...
                    //...
                    continue seek
                }
            }
        }
        //...
        //別thread内で「main thread でしかやってはいけない」処理を書くための定型句
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //...
        }
    }
    //非同期に処理を起動したら、同じメソッド内では何もしてはいけない(と思った方が良い)
```

このコード例では`copyNextSampleBuffer()`が`nil`を返した時の処理が延々と書いてありますが、「頭出し」の位置に至るまでに`nil`が返るのは異常系なので、もうちょっとまとめてさらっと書いても良いかもしれません。重要なのは、「`nil`が帰ってこない限り、ひたすら`copyNextSampleBuffer()`を呼び続けるだけで良い」(非`nil`なら`status`のチェックは不要)と言う点です。

どちらかのコード、必要に応じておためしください。

Comment: timeRange試しました。お陰様でボタンの無効化も考える必要がなくなりました。この質問を書く前から、頭出ししたあとは、その頭からDispatchQueneでフレームを処理しておりました。頭出しも含めてDispatchQuene.globalでやると、動きはするもののwarningが出ておりました。DispatchQueue.main.asyncを使う対処法も試してみます。

Comment: let frameRate = videoTrack.nominalFrameRate
let startTime = CMTime(value: CMTimeValue(startPoint), timescale: 　　　　　　CMTimeScale(frameRate))
let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: startTime, 　　end:kCMTimePositiveInfinity)
reader.timeRange = timeRange 
reader.startReading()

最初の質問はボタンの無効化に関してでしたが、ご教示頂いたソースを使うことで、ビデオの頭出しを一瞬で行える様になり、ボタンを無効化する必要がなくなりました。
CMTimeRangeのパラメーター(.positiveInfinity)は、私の環境では使えず、kCMTimePositiveInfinityを探してきて、使いました。

Comment: @たきちゃん さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。また、ご質問の範囲を無理やり広げさせるようなことをして、混乱させたことお詫びいたします。(気になるなら別質問をあげてください、みたいな書き方をすればよかったかもですね。)とりあえず何がしかのお役に立てたのなら幸いです。`.positiveInfinity`のような定数メンバーに関しては、Swift/iOS SDKのバージョンでコロコロ変わるので、ご質問中にXcodeのバージョン(そこから自動的にSwiftのバージョンも、iOS SDKのバージョンも決まってくる)をご記載いただくと最初からあなたが使いやすいコードを得られる可能性が高まります。今後またご質問を書かれる際には念頭においていただければと思います。で、このサイトでは「承認」のマークは一つの回答にしかつけられません。今回の場合、いち早く元の問題を解決する方法を提示された user17014 さんの回答をご承認いただいた方が良いように思います。(最終的には必要がなくなったと言うことですが、それだけでも残しておく価値のあるQ&Aだと思います。)では、良いアプリが出来上がることをお祈りしています。

Answer (score 0):

Main Threadでループ処理をせず、ループ処理をGCD等でBackground Threadで行うとうまくいくと思います。
以下のような感じでいかがでしょうか？

```
stopButton.isEnabled = false

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    print("ループの前")
    for _ in 0...(startPoint) {
        sample = readerOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
        while reader.status != AVAssetReaderStatus.reading {
            sleep(UInt32(0.1))
        }

    }
    print("ループの後")
}
```

Comment: DispatchQueneで上手く行きました。